# Angular - Rxjs Observable - Clicking event implementation

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around implementing an Observable clicking event to a function I already implemented. The examples I have seen so far are implemented using the `fromEvent` or `Subject` like so;

```
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

export class Component {

    private clickStream$ = new Subject<Event>();

    @Output() observable$ = this.clickStream.asObservable();

    buttonClick(event:Event) {
        this.clickStream$.next(event);
    }
}
```

their html

```
<button type="button" (click)="buttonClick($event)">click me</button>
```

Now consider my implementation below.

component.ts

```
export class MyComponent {
  result;
  public search(queryString: string) {
    this.myService.search().subscribe((res) => result = res )
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
    <input
      formControlName="queryString"
      placeholder="Enter keyword"
      type="text"
      (keyup.enter)="search(searchForm.value.queryString)"
     >
     <div (click)="search(searchForm.value.queryString)"></div> <!-- added an icon with css ->
</form>
```

service.ts

```
export class SearchService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  search(queryString: string) {
    if (!queryString) {
      return;
    }
    return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}&q=${queryString}`);
  }

}
```

My trouble is how to use my current `search()` and still be able to subscribe to my `myService.search()` method while using the approach I found. (i.e. the example code in this post)
I understand ( I think ) streams, and the concept of Observables, but yet this is kicking my butt.

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 1. You need to use the correct method name. `onSearch` is not the same name as `search` and should throw en exception. 2. you can't return anything useful from subscribe. You can make an assignment but `return res` is useless. If you wanted to see the latest value you could create a field in your component and assign to that ore use an async pipe and return an observable from the method (or assign the resulting observable to a field in your component.). 3. Your component method `search` receives an input but you do nothing with that in your service call, why?

Comment: The `@Output()` usage looks wrong. Here is `@Output` explained https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#how-to-use-output

Comment: @Igor sorry I was trying to simply my example here from my original code, so that I'd hide some stuff that doesn't matter afterall. I've updated my examples

Comment: @sneas Do you have a working implementation for using Observables and clicking events in what i'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are  some fundemental issues with your code.

1) There are a few typos, namely the methods such as your service method (`search` or `searchMedPolicies`?)

2) You did not import and initialise your `formGroup` within your component.

3) The way you handle your subscriptions on your component - there is no need to add the return statement on your subscription.

As for your subscription event, you can simply feed the click event to your [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) using `next()`.

Then, you subscribe to your `clickStream$` Subject and make the necessary HTTP requests.

Here are my recommended corrections.

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <input
    formControlName="queryString"
    placeholder="Enter keyword"
    type="text"
    (keyup.enter)="onSearch()"
   >
   <div (click)="onSearch($event)"></div> 
</form>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// other imports 

@Component({
  // etc etc
})

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  clickStream$ = new Subject<Event>();

  searchForm = this.fb.group({
    queryString: '',
  })

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private myService: SearchService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clickStream$
      .pipe(
        switchMap((event) => {            
          const { queryString } = this.searchForm.value;
          // console.log(event);
          // console.log(queryString);

          return this.myService.search(queryString)
        }),
      ).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        // do the rest
      });
  }

  onSearch() {
    this.clickStream$.next(event);
  }
}
```

And on your service.ts, make sure the method names are matching too.

```
export class SearchService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  search(queryString: string) {
    if (!queryString) {
      return;
    }
    return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}&q=${queryString}`);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding some typos and whatnot, I was trying to simplify my example. @wentjun I have initialized the form in my local code, if you have an example of how I could implement the Observable on click that'd be great.

Comment: @Diego done. Basically, what I did is to feed the events to the `clickStream$` subject, and subscribe to it.

Comment: I think my concern is placing that `clickStream$` in the constructor, is there a way to extract to somewhere else, as in not use it in the constructor?

Comment: @Diego yes, you are right. You may place that code in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook instead. Let me make the changes