# Converting button click using EventEmitter to RXJS observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

This is how the component is working with EventEmitter:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-my-component",
  template: ` <button (click)="clickEvent($event)">Foo</button> `
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Output()
  onClick: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  clickEvent(): void {
    this.onClick.emit("something that comes from my.component.ts");
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <h1>Title inside app component.</h1>
    <app-my-component (onClick)="doSomething($event)"></app-my-component>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  doSomething(foo) {
    console.log(foo);
  }
}
```

How can I do the same with an RXJS observable?

I'm trying the following:

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  AfterViewInit,
  Output
} from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-my-component",
  template: ` <button #btn>Foo</button> `
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Output()
  onClick: Observable<string>;

  @ViewChild("btn", { static: true }) buttonRef: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

  foo$: Observable<?>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.foo$ = fromEvent(this.buttonRef.nativeElement, "click").pipe(
      tap((e) => e.stopPropagation())
    );
  }

  // what should be returned here?
  onClick(): Observable<?> {
   return this.foo$
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <h1>Title inside app component.</h1>
    <app-my-component (onClick)="doSomething(event$)"></app-my-component>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  doSomething(foo) {
    console.log(foo);
  }
}
```

Or shouldn't you use RXJS for a click event on a button?

Read various blogposts which were quite old so I didn't find a good source with a proper full example of a button click event. Any pointers in the right direction and a working example would really help out grasping the concept.

Comment: What is your goal? are you trying to pass the event to the parent component only or you want to listen to this event from the unrelated component?

Comment: Good point. The goal is to listen to the event.

Comment: If this is ever relevant, you could use a BehaviorSubject in the parent. 
When the method attached to the child Output is called, you simply call `next()` on your BeaviorSubect with the value of the $event.
Wherever you need to listen to this value, use it with :
`mySubect.asObservable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen such an approach in angular for a button click and you are already using RxJS with EventEmitter :)

check it out: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

EventEmitter extends Subject, so if you want to use RxJS directly - try to use it instead. You can check this answer [Angular - Rxjs Observable - Clicking event implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543296/angular-rxjs-observable-clicking-event-implementation) with a good explanation

Also, using the native element is discouraged by Angular

Comment: Thanks for the links and your perspective. The implementation I copied was https://gist.github.com/Armenvardanyan95/c2830b325f98b1b588a12d8ce98d9a06#file-not-convoluted-ts, from this article: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/rxjs-in-angular-part-1c5409610d8e

Comment: he uses it for *ngIf, and it is okayish. His approach I would update to use: combineLatest(buttonClickBehaviorSubjectAsObservable, documentClickBehaviorSubjectAsObservable) in variable(no need to update it). this 2 BehaviorSubjects would start from false and would be triggered with .next(true): click on click, and body on HostListener